# How to set the nodes color with a given graph

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

I am using  **networkx** and **matplotlib**

Now I want to set the color of nodes,and I read the graph from text file

```
G=nx.read_edgelist("Edge.txt")
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Here is the Edge file of example

```
0 1
0 2
3 4
```

Here is what I did,and is failed

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.read_edgelist("Edge.txt")
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_list=[0,1,2],node_color='B')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_list=[3,4],node_color='R')
plt.show()
```

the result is a lot of **blue nodes without edges**

So if I want to set the NodeListA=[0,1,2] to blue, NodeListB=[3,4] to red

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

draw the nodes explicitly by calling the top-level function, **draw_networkx_nodes**

and pass in your node list as the value for the parameter **node_list**, and value for the parameter **node_color**, like so

```
nx.draw_network_nodes(G, pos, node_list=NodeListA, node_color="#5072A7")
```

the argument pos is just a python dictionary whose keys are the nodes of the graph and the values are x, y positions; an easy to to supply pos is to pass your graph object to **spring_layout** which will return the dictionary.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

alternatively, you can pass in the dictionary directly, e.g.,

```
pos = {
       0:(2,2),
       1:(3,5),
       2:(1,2),
       3:(5,5),
       4:(7,4)
}
```

the likely cause of the code in the OP to execute is the call to read_edgelist; in particular, the file passed in is probably incorrectly formatted.

here's how to check this and also how to fix it:

```
G = nx.path_graph(5)

df = "/path/to/my/graphinit.edgelist"

nx.write_edgelist(G, df)    # save a properly formatted edgelist file

G = nx.read_edgelist(df)    # read that file back in
```

Comment: I have try it. but I don't know how to set the pos. Exactly ,I have almost 300 nodes and 800 edges . when I use nx.spring_layout() ,I get an error.

Comment: you need to pass in your graph object, "G", nx.spring_layout(G)

Comment: see my Answer, at the end. (The only other source of failure is the call to graphviz_layout, so if what i have above does not work then replace graphviz_layout with spring_layout and see what happens.

Comment: >>> nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_list=[0,1,2],node_color='B')
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x4316910>            This is the information. After you steps,there are  {} afte every edges. But plt.show() shows the picture with red nodes only ,without edges too